# debug symbol file for linux kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I want to debug both my QEMU source code and Linux kernel source code(ported to a particular board) when trying to boot the kernel image on QEMU.

So i start something like this :

Step 1 : $gdb qemu-system-arm

step 2 : $break { list of breakpoints in qemu src }

step 3 : $run {kernel image} {boot loader image}

step 4 : open another console

step 5 : $arm-none-eabi-gdb

step 6 : $file  {load debug symbol file for compiled kernel src}

Ques : what file in the compiled kernel src contains the debug symbols ?

If i load the same kernel image, it says file format not recognized.

I tried this with a sample bare metal code and i was able to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Symbols can usually be found in [System.map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map). Concerning 'file format not recognized', make sure you aren't trying to load a compressed image.